# sqlite3 via sqlalchemy write operation is slow on USB drive

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, usb-drive

I am using `sqlite3` via `sqlalchemy` package in Python 3.7. The SQLite database file is stored on a USB 2.0 flash drive, plugged in a MacBook Pro.

Even though many times I don't have problems, but sometimes I see a write operation (for example, a transaction of updating 2 tables in a commit) would be very slow, e.g. 8 seconds. This happens frequent enough that I have to debug it.  In good times, the same operation takes less than 0.5 second.

My question is: how can I distinguish where this slowness is in `sqlalchemy` or in `sqlite3` or just the USB driver itself? I was not able to find an existing post with such problem.

(I was wondering if I should replace USB 2.0 drive with USB 3.0 drive, maybe because USB 2.0 is half-duplex? But I'm not sure and wanted to see if any way to confirm).

Comment: Are you using WAL journal mode?

Comment: The speed of a flash drive is not only dependent on the USB standard (2.0 vs 3.0) but also the chipset inside. See https://usb.userbenchmark.com/ for some benchmarks.

Comment: @Shawn how should I enable WAL mode using `sqlalchemy` ? I tried to mimic the example code at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html (search set_sqlite_pragma) but it did not work.

Comment: @Shawn looks like I was able to change to WAL mode (the `sqlalchemy` sample code is strange as it's called per connection event, I had to make sure only change the WAL mode once).   My test result shows the performance is a bit better (6 seconds vs previously 8 seconds) but still not as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I went out and bought a USB 3.1 drive (SanDisk), so with nothing else changed,  the performance is greatly improved:  the max latency is reduced from 12 seconds to 0.25 second. Looks like USB 2.0 drive was the main cause of the slowness. (Sqlite3 WAL mode helped a bit too). Thanks for comments from @Shawn and @Selcuk.